# Find all files of name recursively, touch, and chmod all in one terminal command?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal

I am trying to run a single command to change all **.DS_Store** files within a directory and all subdirectories *recursively*.

So far, I have been using the following commands to find the files, set their date modified to `Jan 1 01:01:01 2001`, and then to find them and set their permissions to `read only` for user, group, and everyone .

```
find . -name '.DS_Store' -print0 | xargs -0 sudo touch -t 200101010101
find . -name '.DS_Store' -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 444
```

I'm guessing there is a more efficient way to do this with a single command, but I'm not sure how to use the output of the `find` command in more than a single following command.

Ideally, if there is any error/failure encountered with any of the files/commands, I would want to have the command line stop and output the error message rather than continuing to execute. I've seen elsewhere that using `&&` to separate commands on a single line would do this, but am not sure how to use this in conjunction with the output from the `find` command.

This question is about a smaller part of a larger task I'm trying to accomplish. I've almost got it all working now except part of the script that only seems to work when I run it from terminal directly. Here's a link to the main issue in case anyone here might be able to help: [Service to execute series of commands on selected folders to eliminate issues with .DS_Store files in Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/1732814/service-to-execute-series-of-commands-on-selected-folders-to-eliminate-issues-wi)

Comment: Do you want it to be more efficient in terms of typing (shorter command), or in terms of execution time (CPU/IO usage)?

Comment: Ideally, execution time. length of command not as important. thanks!

Comment: Does macOS come with Python (or at least Perl) these days? Most methods based on `find` would either negate the benefit of 'xargs' (running two commands _per file_) or wouldn't have sufficient error checking.

Comment: I have no idea what "these days" you refer to specifically, but I'm a die-hard holdout still using macOS Sierra (10.12.6). Maybe that would help to answer that question? :) In case not, here's a ink to a screenshot of the relevant results found on my system using *Find Any File*. https://i.imgur.com/AiHD8Ed.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using the `-exec` option and using its output as argument for a subshell:

```
find . -name '.DS_Store' -exec zsh -c 'touch -t 200101010101 "$1" && sudo chmod 444 "$1" || echo "$1" >> errors.txt' zsh {} \;
```

As you can see I use `zsh {}` to pass an argument to `zsh -c`, which allows me to use the output of find via `$1`. Note that you need to use double quotes here, e.g. to avoid filenames containing spaces causing problems.

I use `&&` to only continue with the next command, if the previous exited without an error.

If an error occurs, `||` allows me to run a command on failure, for example writing the filename into a `errors.txt` file.

Comment: @MikMak I am not aware of any difference in particular, but I've read about some arguments behaving different as well as some missing/different functionality. As I couldn't test this on a MacOS or BSD machine yet, I've added the note.

Comment: @MikMak as you've accepted the answer, I suppose it works on MacOS without any problems. I will remove the note then.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
find . -name '.DS_Store' -exec sudo touch -t 200101010101 {} + -exec sudo chmod 444 {} + -print
```

(remember, -exec with + builds a single command with all files as arguments)